# How to make jersey client call to url in format http://ppp.com/yy?zz,aa,bb

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have searched through a lot but i am not able to figure out the solution to issue.

I have an external url which i want to call using jersey rest api. The url is in format http://ppp.com/yy?zz,aa,bb.

If i use queryparam then it gives url pattern '?test=data' but i don't want '=' after test. How can i create this specific pattern of url using jersey. Below is same code with issue.

```
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
 WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI()).path("yy").queryParam("zz,aa,bb","");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you need such a URL, but

```
WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI()).path("yy?zz,aa,bb")
```

Just build your `path` parameter prior to passing it in.

Comment: I also don't like the structure of this url but its some school stuff i have to finish. Also putting ? in path gives out %3F when finally making call instead of ?

Comment: @Novice_JS what do these zz,aa,bb mean? Because it's not a *valid* URL.

Comment: zz,aa,bb are for filtering. like http://google.com/images?imagesForCars,apples,idiots. Some idiot designed really bad api and now i have to use it to complete some stuff.

Comment: @Novice_JS well that's not even a valid URL format, so bad would be an understatement